# pandas read_csv convert value '?' to NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this csv dataset Train.csv. The file contains '?' instead of null(NaN) values. I have imported the file using read_csv method. I want to replace all such '?' with np.NaN value but the following code isn't working:

```
df.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace = True, regex = False)
```

I don't want to use regex.
Please help.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Maybe check for leading or trailing whitespace..? eg `" ?"`

Comment: I checked and there were Whiteapaces in every entry. Thank you so much @ChrisA

Answer (score 3):

You can try to import the data using pandas read_csv with the option na_values:

```
pd.read_csv('Train.csv', na_values="?")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I checked there were whitespaces @Grzegorz